Partial Derivative Equations - independent variable wrt dependent one
We're given a general partial derivative equation of the form:
${R}z_{xx} + {S}z_{xy} + Tz_{yy} + f({x,y,z,p,q})=0$
${R}, {S}, {T}$ are continuous functions of ${x},{y}$ possessing partial derivates.
This is simplified by taking two functions $u=u(x,y)$ and $v =v(x,y)$ and rewriting original equation in terms of $u$ and $v$
This is what the textbook says:
$$p = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}.\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $$
$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial }{\partial u} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial }{\partial v}$$
$$r = \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} = (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial }{\partial u} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial }{\partial v})(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}) = z_{uu}.u_{x}^2+z_{vv}.v_{x}^2 + 2z_{uv}u_{x}v_{x} + z_{u}u_{xx}+z_{v}v_{xx}$$
I did not understand how we got the terms $z_{u}u_{xx}$ and $z_{v}v_{xx}$
How is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial }{\partial u}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}) = z_{uu}.u_{x}^2 + z_{u}u_{xx}$ ?

The terms $z_{u}u_{xx},z_{v}v_{xx}$ come from applying the product rule to $z_{u}u_{x}$ and $z_{v}v_{x}$. If $z(x, y) \to z(u(x, y), v(x, y))$ then \begin{align} z_{x} &\to \color{red}{z_{u}} \color{green}{u_{x}} + \color{blue}{z_{v}} \color{orange}{v_{x}} \ z_{xx} &\to (\color{red}{z_{uu} u_{x} + z_{uv} v_{x}}) \color{green}{u_{x}} + \color{red}{z_{u}} \color{green}{u_{xx}} + (\color{blue}{z_{vu} u_{x} + z_{vv} v_{x}}) \color{orange}{v_{x}} + \color{blue}{z_{v}} \color{orange}{v_{xx}} \end{align} which is the expression you have labelled $r$.

@MatthewCassell this makes sense now.
Writing it in the form of an operator like
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial }{\partial u} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial }{\partial v}$ was confusing me.
Your formatting simplified it for me. thanks

I understood where the confusion arose. I was failing to apply the chain rule due to the way the $\partial$ operator is written.
If we write $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ as:
$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial u} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial v}$$
I was finding it difficult to evaluate
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial }{\partial u} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)$$
Rewriting as the following helped
\begin{align}
z_{x} &= z_{u}u_{x} + z_{v}v_{x} \\
z_{xx} &= (z_{uu}u_{x} + z_{uv}v_{x})u_{x} + z_{u}u_{xx} + (z_{vu}u_{x} + z_{vv}v_{x})v_{x} + z_{v}v_{xx} \\
&= z_{uu}u_{x}^2 + 2u_{x}v_{x}z_{uv} + z_{vv}v_{x}^2 + z_{u}u_{xx}+ z_{v}v_{xx}
\end{align}
